# Hilo en java no corre sino coloco un System.out.println dentro un ciclo while que a su vez esta dentro del metodo run

Tags: java, hilos

Como mencioné en el título de la pregunta, tengo un *hilo* en Java que no funciona el método `run`, si es que no pongo un `System.out.println()` dentro de un ciclo `while`.

Abajo les dejo el código de las clases.

Clase personaje principal:

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JComponent;


public class PersonajePrincipal extends JComponent implements KeyListener, Runnable{
    
    private final double XInicial=150;
    private final double YInicial=Funcion.suelo(XInicial);  
    private Image        imagen;
    private double       x=XInicial,y=YInicial;
    private Dimension    dimensiones=new Dimension(30,70);//20,50
    private boolean      salto=false;
    private boolean      detener=false;
    
    
    public PersonajePrincipal(int ancho, int alto, String ruta){
        setBounds(0,0,ancho+2000,alto);
        try {
            imagen=ImageIO.read(new File(ruta));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setOpaque(false);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(imagen,(int)x,(int)(y-dimensiones.height),dimensiones.width,dimensiones.height,null);
        
    }
    
    public void moverX(int dx) {
        x=x+dx;
        y=Funcion.suelo(x);  
        //repaint();
    }
    
    public void moverY(int dy) {
        y=y+dy;
        //repaint();
    }
    
    public void run() {
        
        try {
             Thread.sleep(320);
            
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        salto=true;
         saltar();
         salto=false;
        
    }
    
    public Dimension getDimensiones() {
        return dimensiones;
    }
    
    public void saltar() {
        for(int i=1;i<=15;i++) {
            x=x+10;
            y=y-20;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //repaint();
        }
    double deltaY=Math.abs(Funcion.suelo(x+100)-y)/15;
        for(int i=1;i<15;i++) {
            x=x+10;
            y=y+deltaY;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //repaint();
        }
        
        
        
        moverX(0);
        }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
        if(k.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
           if(!salto&&!detener)
            moverX(4);
            
            
          }else if(k.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                       if(!salto&&!detener)
                       moverX(-4);
                       
                 }else if(k.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL) {
                              if(!detener) {
                                Thread hilo=new Thread(this);
                                hilo.start();
                              }
                        }
        
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {
        
    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k) {
        
        
    }
    public Point puntoXY() {
        return new Point((int)x,(int)y);
    }
    public void setDetener() {
        detener=true;
    }
    }
```

La clase de un enemigo:

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Enemigos extends Component implements Runnable{
    
    private final int XInicial=500;
    private final int XFinal=700;
    private Image     imagen;
    private int       x=XInicial,y;
    private Dimension dimensionImagen=new Dimension(40,90);//20,50
    private boolean   acabarHilo;
    
    public Enemigos(int ancho, int alto, String ruta){
       setBounds(0,0,ancho,alto);
       try {
           imagen=ImageIO.read(new File(ruta));
       } catch (IOException e) {
        
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       //setOpaque(false);
       Thread hilo=new Thread(this);
       hilo.setDaemon(true);
       hilo.start();
    
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
        g.drawImage(imagen,x,y-dimensionImagen.height,dimensionImagen.width,dimensionImagen.height,null);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int cambioUnitario=1;
        while(!acabarHilo) {
            x=x+cambioUnitario;
            y=(int)Funcion.suelo(x);
            //repaint();
            if(x==XInicial||x==XFinal) {
                cambioUnitario=-cambioUnitario;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15);//25
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public Point puntoXY() {
        return new Point(x,y);
    }
    public void setAcabarHilo() {
        acabarHilo=true;
    }
    public Dimension getDimensiones() {
        return dimensionImagen;
    }
    
    }
```

La clase de otro enemigo

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Bola extends Component implements Runnable{
    private final int XInicial=800;
    private final int YInicial=(int)Funcion.suelo(XInicial);
    private Image     imagen;
    private int       x=XInicial,y=YInicial;
    private Dimension dimensionImagen=new Dimension(50,50);//20,50
    private boolean   acabarHilo=false;
    
    public Bola(int ancho, int alto, String ruta){
       setBounds(0,0,ancho,alto);
       try {
           imagen=ImageIO.read(new File(ruta));
       } catch (IOException e) {
        
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       //setOpaque(false);
       Thread hilo=new Thread(this);
       hilo.setDaemon(true);
       hilo.start();
    
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        g.drawImage(imagen,x,y-dimensionImagen.height,dimensionImagen.width,dimensionImagen.height,null);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int cambioUnitario=-1;
        while(!acabarHilo) {
            y=y+cambioUnitario;
            //repaint();
            if(y==YInicial||y==YInicial-200) {
                cambioUnitario=-cambioUnitario;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15);//25
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public Point puntoXY() {
        return new Point(x,y);
    }
    public void setAcabarHilo() {
        acabarHilo=true;
    }
    public Dimension getDimensiones() {
        return dimensionImagen;
    }
    
   }
```

La clase donde esta el contenedor principal que dibuja las otras componentes(inicialmente lo hice con un JPanel pero lo cambie):

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;


public class Paisaje extends Container implements Runnable{
    
    private PersonajePrincipal mario;
    private Enemigos bowser;
    private Bola bola;
    private Polygon poligono;
    
    
    public Paisaje(int ancho,int alto) {
        setBounds(0,0,ancho+2000,alto);
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(new Color(51,165,255));
        mario=new PersonajePrincipal(ancho,alto,"mario bros.png");
        add(mario);
        bowser=new Enemigos(ancho,alto,"bowser1.png");
        add(bowser);
        bola= new Bola(ancho,alto,"bola.png");
        add(bola);
        
        poligono=new Polygon();
        poligono.addPoint(120,500);
        poligono.addPoint(320,300);
        poligono.addPoint(500,300);
        poligono.addPoint(700,500);
        Thread hilo=new Thread(this);
        hilo.start();       
    }
    public PersonajePrincipal getPersonaje() {
        return mario;
    }
    public Enemigos getBowser() {
        return bowser;
    }
    public Bola getBola() {
        return bola;
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setColor(new Color(57,157,18));
        g2.fillRect(0, 500, 1000, 300);
        g2.fillPolygon(poligono);
        g2.fillRect(1200,500, 1200, 300);
    }
    public void gameOver() {
       Graphics g=this.getGraphics();
       ImageIcon imagen=new ImageIcon("game over.png");
       g.drawImage(imagen.getImage(),this.getWidth()/2-100-mario.puntoXY().x/2,this.getHeight()/2-100,400,200,null);
     }
    
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            this.setLocation(150-mario.puntoXY().x,0);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            repaint();          
        }
        
    }
    
    
    }
```

La clase de la ventana:

```java
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Ventana extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    private Rectangle e=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
    private Paisaje paisaje;
    
    
    public Ventana() {
        int ancho=(int)e.getWidth(), alto=(int)e.getHeight();
        setBounds(0,0,ancho,alto);
        setLayout(null);
        paisaje = new Paisaje(ancho, alto);
        addKeyListener(paisaje.getPersonaje());
        add(paisaje);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Thread hilo = new Thread(this);
        hilo.start();
        
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean condicion=true;
        while(condicion) {
            condicion=!Funcion.interaccion(paisaje.getPersonaje(), paisaje.getBowser(), paisaje.getBola());
            
        }
        paisaje.getPersonaje().setDetener();
        paisaje.getBowser().setAcabarHilo();
        paisaje.getBola().setAcabarHilo();
        paisaje.gameOver();
    }
    
}
```

Y este es el codigo de la clase donde se define la funcion estatica

```java
public class Funcion {

    public static double suelo(double x){
           double retorno=0;
           if(x>=0&&x<100) {
              retorno=500;
           }else if(x<300) {
              retorno=-x+600;
           }else if(x<500) {
              retorno=300;
           }else if(x<700) {
              retorno=-200+x;
           }else if(x<1000) {
              retorno=500;
           }else if(x<1200) {
              retorno=700; 
           }else if(x<3500) {
               retorno=500;
           }
           return retorno;
    }
    public static void dibujarSuelo(Graphics g) {
        for(int i=0;i<1500;i++) {
            g.drawLine(i,(int)Funcion.suelo(i),i+1 ,(int)Funcion.suelo(i+1));
        }
    }
    public static boolean interaccion(PersonajePrincipal mario, Enemigos bowser, Bola bola) {
        double separacionX =Math.abs(mario.puntoXY().x-bowser.puntoXY().x);
        double separacionY =Math.abs(mario.puntoXY().y-bowser.puntoXY().y);
        double separacionX2 =Math.abs(mario.puntoXY().x-bola.puntoXY().x);
        double separacionY2 =Math.abs(mario.puntoXY().y-bola.puntoXY().y);
        return((separacionX<mario.getDimensiones().width&&separacionY<mario.getDimensiones().height)||(separacionX2<mario.getDimensiones().width&&(separacionY2<mario.getDimensiones().height)));
        
    }
    }
```

Y finalmente la clase principal con el metodo `main`:

```java
public class Principal3{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
             Ventana ventana=  new Ventana();
             //Thread hilo= new Thread(ventana);
            //hilo.start();
    }

}
```

Agradecería mucho a quien pudiera explicar el porqué de esto, y cómo mejorarlo.

Comment: Podrías agregar mas detalles, como por ejemplo, como es que te das cuenta que no funciona?...con el código que nos muestras es imposible que lo probemos

Comment: Agregar un `System.out.println()` **NO** hará que funcione un hilo que "no funciona". En tu caso debes decirno que entiendes por ***no funciona***. Agrega el código completo de la clase que contiene el método `run()` y el código donde ejecutas el hilo.

Comment: @E. Betanzos ahi subi las clases donde se define la funcion que usa el metodo run y la clase donde se declara el metodo run. Por "no funciona" me refiero a que no realiza la funcion  que debería.

Comment: Les dejo un link a un video explicando lo que hace el programa https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVaBNXVoCkA

Comment: Tu código no depende para nada del contenido de la consola, por lo que imprimir algo en esta NO tiene porqué cambiar el comportamineto del programa. Puedes agregar un `System.out.println(condición)` a ver que indica?

Comment: @E. Betanzos mire estimado https://youtu.be/OGx5y5y2Llc

Comment: Podrías compartir el código completo para poder probarlo?

Comment: @E. Betanzos ahi lo subi

Comment: Las imágenes que añadiste no son necesarias, se puede tomar como vandalismo a tu propia publicación si las mismas no apartan nada relevante a la pregunta. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te está ocurriendo en un problema de sincronización entre hilos derivado de la ejecución de los distintos hilos de una aplicación en diferentes núcleos de un procesador y del modo en que se comparten y actualizan los datos entre estos.

[Este artículo](https://medium.com/@pablocastelnovo/variables-vol%C3%A1tiles-en-java-f5ae078bf8b9) te puede ayudar a entender mejor el porqué te ocurre esto.

Mi solución es que definas los métodos `puntoXY()` de las clases `PersonajePrincipal`, `Enemigos` y `Bola` de la siguiente manera.

```
public synchronized Point puntoXY() {
    // código del método
}
```

Comment: soluciono el problema, muchas gracias Dios te bendiga

Comment: Muchas gracias @Julioenriquegodoymuñoz, un saludo.